# Volume generated by rotating axis $X =2$ and the lines $x =0$ and $y = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, rotations, solid-of-revolution

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bysp3.jpg)

I wrote the shaded area equation and add 2 to it because it has shifted two units to the right, however the answer is wrong, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in assuming the general equation for the volume of rotation to be

$$
V=\pi\int y^2dx
$$

but in fact, for rotation about a vertical axis it should be

$$
V=2\pi\int xydx
$$

If you make the substitution $X=x-2$ and apply the above equation you will have

$$
V=2\pi\int_0^1 X\sqrt{1-X}\ dX
$$

I will leave it to you to show that the correct answer is $V=8\pi/15$.